# Contests/questions based on external games

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of interesting ideas out there, in the form of existing games.

There is also a strict rule that anything posted on SE must be [licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Where is the line between **unacceptable** posting of someone else's copyrighted game idea as a question, and **acceptable** use of a copyrighted game as an inspiration? *Separating your key ideas into short, separate answers will allow the votes to show community consensus.*

Discussion in chat occasionally turns towards  existing board games or computer games that might make a good code golf or king of the hill contest, and I'd like to see some clear guidance on what we need to bear in mind.

Answer (score 7):

[According to this GameDev.SE post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/11764/19876) gameplay is not copyrightable. Hence, any game mechanic can be turned into a challenge. The legal issues which you need to worry about are:

- The *textual expression* of the rules does qualify for copyright protection, so you should explain them in your own words.
- Don't reuse any assets (which is unlikely on PPCG anyway)
- Maybe refrain from using trademarked names, like specific Pokémons.
- In some cases the game mechanics may be patented.

Further sources:

- [U.S. Copyright Office](http://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl108.html)
- [Article on NYTimes.com](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/03/12/technology/for-creators-of-video-games-a-faint-line-on-cloning.html?_r=2&pagewanted=all&)